# Is there a way to filter logged elmah entries by the http code?

Tags: elmah

I know that I can stop http code 404 errors from been registered on elmah on the configuration.

But I want to register 404 and 500 errors, however in some situations I want to see only the 500.

Can I pass some url param like the "page" and "size" to the elmah.axd to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Longer: if you store your elmah errors in SQL server or another data store supporting search, you can write custom SQL or whatever query language your DB support.

I'm the founder of https://elmah.io (which support search). We also wrote an errorLog implementation for elmah that store data i Elasticsearch. With Kibana on top, you can create a custom dashboard with filters. You can find the error logger here: https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.ElasticSearch

Comment: can I combine multiple data store as you do on log4net for example?

Comment: Multiple error loggers are not supported, but there's a small hack to make it happen: http://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-multiple-elmah-logs/. In that example you should create an instance of an errorlogger of your choice within the event handler.